# If / Else function is doing both parts not one part

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Both the if and the else part of my function is running.

It should do something like this:

- I have 3 cells on a sheet and I want to stop the function if the user has not entered in all 3 cells. (a google form is not appropriate)
- If all 3 cells are there, move the values to the archive sheet
- else prompt and do nothing.

I have tried different variations of === and !==

I am using submitFeedback() through a custom menu onOpen if this makes any difference.

```
function submitFeedback() {
  var feedback = ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("B3:D3").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");
  var ref = ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("B3");
  var customer = ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("C3");
  var type = ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("D3");
  var archive = ss.getSheetByName("Feedback Archive");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var incomplete = ui.alert('Please complete all fields');
  if(ref !== "" && customer !== "" && type !== "") {
  archive.appendRow(feedback);
  ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("B3:D3").clearContent();
  } else {
  return incomplete;
  }
}
```

I have found some similar questions on here but none that have helped me make this work.

Also interested in knowing if there is a tidier way to check if the range "Feedback" is full

Comment: You can try making incomplete a function and call it in the else block. `var incomplete = () =>ui.alert('Please complete all fields');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that smth was broken in JS and if statement started working incorrectly.
I assume, that first branch of if statement works in your case. However, your prompt runs before, that's why you think that both branches work. Look:

```
function submitFeedback() {
  var feedback = ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("B3:D3").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");
  var ref = ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("B3");
  var customer = ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("C3");
  var type = ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("D3");
  var archive = ss.getSheetByName("Feedback Archive");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var incomplete = ui.alert('Please complete all fields'); // <= Prompt runs here

  if(ref !== "" && customer !== "" && type !== "") {
     // This branch is executed;
  archive.appendRow(feedback);
  ss.getSheetByName("Submit Feedback").getRange("B3:D3").clearContent();
  } else {
  return incomplete;
  }
}
```

Regarding your second question

> Also interested in knowing if there is a tidier way to check if the range "Feedback" is full

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) it seems that there is a way to check if range is totaly blank but there is no way to check if it's fully filled with data. However, you solution regarding this part looks pretty good, as to me

Answer (score 0):

The if else looks good. I think the `var incomplete = ui.alert('Please complete all fields');` to be where the return statement is. I think you just need `return ui.alert('Please complete all fields');`. Or even just `ui.alert('Please complete all fields');` where the return statement is.